# Errors in Toplink Map and Offline database files when migrating from jDev 10.1.3.4 to jDev 11.2.1

Tags: java, oracle, migration, jdeveloper, toplink

i'm migrating an application from jDev 10.3.1.4 (Using Equivalent version of OC4J and Toplink 3.0) to the latest to jDev 11.2.1. I'm encountering a lot of problems.
First of all a general question, are there some in depth migration guides?This looks like is gonna be a total pain in the ass (Sorry for the expression)
Now some more precise question.

- i have errors in offline database files. I get the message: WARNING: Offline Database file does not exist for file "TIPO_STAG.table" for every single offline database file. I have configured my database connection, but i don't know what is happening.
- i have the following exception shown when i open the Toplink Map:

> Local Exception Stack: Exception [TOPLINK-6044] (Oracle TopLink - 11g
>   Release 1 (11.1.1.5.0) (Build 110305)):
>   oracle.toplink.exceptions.QueryException Exception Description: The
>   primary key read from the row [DatabaseRecord()] during the execution
>   of the query was detected to be null. Primary keys must not contain
>   null. Query:
>   ReadAllQuery(oracle.toplink.workbench.mappingsmodel.database.MWLegacyTable)
>   at
>   oracle.toplink.exceptions.QueryException.nullPrimaryKeyInBuildingObject(QueryException.java:837)
>   at
>   oracle.toplink.internal.descriptors.ObjectBuilder.buildObject(ObjectBuilder.java:418)
>   at
>   oracle.toplink.internal.descriptors.ObjectBuilder.buildObjectsInto(ObjectBuilder.java:748)
>   at
>   oracle.toplink.internal.queryframework.DatabaseQueryMechanism.buildObjectsFromRows(DatabaseQueryMechanism.java:170)
>   at
>   oracle.toplink.queryframework.ReadAllQuery.executeObjectLevelReadQuery(ReadAllQuery.java:477)
>   at
>   oracle.toplink.queryframework.ObjectLevelReadQuery.executeDatabaseQuery(ObjectLevelReadQuery.java:874)
>   at
>   oracle.toplink.queryframework.DatabaseQuery.execute(DatabaseQuery.java:679)
>   at
>   oracle.toplink.queryframework.ObjectLevelReadQuery.execute(ObjectLevelReadQuery.java:835)
>   at
>   oracle.toplink.queryframework.ReadAllQuery.execute(ReadAllQuery.java:445)
>   at
>   oracle.toplink.internal.sessions.AbstractSession.internalExecuteQuery(AbstractSession.java:2265)
>   at
>   oracle.toplink.internal.sessions.AbstractSession.executeQuery(AbstractSession.java:1079)
>   at
>   oracle.toplink.internal.sessions.AbstractSession.executeQuery(AbstractSession.java:1063)
>   at
>   oracle.toplink.internal.indirection.NoIndirectionPolicy.valueFromQuery(NoIndirectionPolicy.java:264)
>   at
>   oracle.toplink.mappings.ForeignReferenceMapping.valueFromRowInternal(ForeignReferenceMapping.java:1377)
>   at
>   oracle.toplink.mappings.ForeignReferenceMapping.valueFromRow(ForeignReferenceMapping.java:1306)
>   at
>   oracle.toplink.mappings.DatabaseMapping.readFromRowIntoObject(DatabaseMapping.java:1117)
>   at
>   oracle.toplink.internal.descriptors.ObjectBuilder.buildAttributesIntoObject(ObjectBuilder.java:279)
>   at
>   oracle.toplink.sdk.SDKAggregateObjectMapping.buildCompositeObject(SDKAggregateObjectMapping.java:58)
>   at
>   oracle.toplink.mappings.foundation.AbstractCompositeObjectMapping.valueFromRow(AbstractCompositeObjectMapping.java:231)
>   at
>   oracle.toplink.mappings.DatabaseMapping.readFromRowIntoObject(DatabaseMapping.java:1117)
>   at
>   oracle.toplink.internal.descriptors.ObjectBuilder.buildAttributesIntoObject(ObjectBuilder.java:279)
>   at
>   oracle.toplink.internal.descriptors.ObjectBuilder.buildObject(ObjectBuilder.java:584)
>   at
>   oracle.toplink.internal.descriptors.ObjectBuilder.buildObject(ObjectBuilder.java:441)
>   at
>   oracle.toplink.internal.descriptors.ObjectBuilder.buildObject(ObjectBuilder.java:391)
>   at
>   oracle.toplink.queryframework.ObjectLevelReadQuery.buildObject(ObjectLevelReadQuery.java:511)
>   at
>   oracle.toplink.queryframework.ReadObjectQuery.executeObjectLevelReadQuery(ReadObjectQuery.java:433)
>   at
>   oracle.toplink.queryframework.ObjectLevelReadQuery.executeDatabaseQuery(ObjectLevelReadQuery.java:874)
>   at
>   oracle.toplink.queryframework.DatabaseQuery.execute(DatabaseQuery.java:679)
>   at
>   oracle.toplink.queryframework.ObjectLevelReadQuery.execute(ObjectLevelReadQuery.java:835)
>   at
>   oracle.toplink.queryframework.ReadObjectQuery.execute(ReadObjectQuery.java:397)
>   at
>   oracle.toplink.internal.sessions.AbstractSession.internalExecuteQuery(AbstractSession.java:2265)
>   at
>   oracle.toplink.internal.sessions.AbstractSession.executeQuery(AbstractSession.java:1079)
>   at
>   oracle.toplink.internal.sessions.AbstractSession.executeQuery(AbstractSession.java:1063)
>   at
>   oracle.toplink.internal.sessions.AbstractSession.executeQuery(AbstractSession.java:1022)
>   at
>   oracle.toplink.internal.sessions.AbstractSession.readObject(AbstractSession.java:2827)
>   at
>   oracle.toplink.workbench.mappingsio.legacy.PersistenceTools50.readMWProjectNamed(PersistenceTools50.java:331)
>   at
>   oracle.toplink.workbench.mappingsio.legacy.LegacyIOFacade.read50Project(LegacyIOFacade.java:29)
>   at
>   oracle.toplink.workbench.mappingsio.ProjectReader.readLegacyProject(ProjectReader.java:296)
>   at
>   oracle.toplink.workbench.mappingsio.ProjectReader.read(ProjectReader.java:110)
>   at
>   oracle.toplink.workbench.mappingsio.ProjectIOManager.read(ProjectIOManager.java:64)
>   at
>   oracle.toplink.workbench.mappingsio.ProjectIOManager.read(ProjectIOManager.java:60)
>   at
>   oracle.toplink.workbench.addin.application.ProjectContext.buildProject(ProjectContext.java:160)
>   at
>   oracle.toplink.workbench.addin.application.ProjectContext.initialize(ProjectContext.java:440)
>   at
>   oracle.toplink.workbench.addin.application.ProjectContext.(ProjectContext.java:106)
>   at
>   oracle.toplink.workbench.addin.application.ContextManager.openProject(ContextManager.java:1169)
>   at
>   oracle.toplink.workbench.addin.application.ContextManager.openTopLinkMap(ContextManager.java:1218)
>   at
>   oracle.toplink.workbench.addin.application.ContextManager.loadProjectContext(ContextManager.java:1068)
>   at
>   oracle.toplink.workbench.addin.application.ContextManager.getContext(ContextManager.java:657)
>   at
>   oracle.toplink.workbench.addin.ui.view.TopLinkContextViewContextBuilder.topLinkContext(TopLinkContextViewContextBuilder.java:202)
>   at
>   oracle.toplink.workbench.addin.ui.view.TopLinkContextViewContextBuilder.openDocument(TopLinkContextViewContextBuilder.java:187)
>   at
>   oracle.toplink.workbench.addin.ui.view.ViewContextManager$OpenDocument.run(ViewContextManager.java:1081)

Of course non of those problems were present in the old version. Thanks for your help